# Custom table data not shown in tempalte file Magento 2

Tags: layout, blocks, phtml

> \app\code\Packt\welcome\Block\Post.php

```
namespace Packt\welcome\Block;
class Post extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_postFactory;
        protected  $postdata;

        public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                \Packt\welcome\model\postFactory $postFactory, array $data = array()){
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }
        public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
        $collection = $post->getCollection();


        foreach($collection as $item){
            $postlist[]=array("data"=> $item->getData());

        }

                //print_r($postlist);

               return $postlist;
    }
}
```

> Here print_r shows the data.

```
Layout :\app\code\Packt\welcome\view\frontend\layout\welcome_index_postdisplay.xml
```

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Packt\welcome\Block\Post" name="welcome" template="post.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> \app\code\Packt\welcome\view\frontend\templates\post.phtml

```
<?php var_dump($block->_prepareLayout());?>
```

**But when I call the function from template file it shows nothing.**

Comment: **W** capital in welcome module name.

Comment: your template is rendering correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your custom code in `_prepareLayout` function. 
Create another function like

```
public function getPost()
{
    $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
    $collection = $post->getCollection();


    foreach($collection as $item){
        $postlist[]=array("data"=> $item->getData());

    }

            //print_r($postlist);

           return $postlist;
}
```

and call the function in template like below:

```
<?php var_dump($block->getPost());?>
```

Comment: I have changed the function as you mentioned but still it is not showing the data. when I typed the url "<domain.dev>/welcome/index/postdisplay" it shows home page.
I have added _prepareLayout(){parent::_prepareLayout();} and create new function  public function getPostData(){//same code as before;}. called it from .phtml "<?php var_dump($block->getPostData());?>"

Comment: Pls check naming convention, W must be capital in for module name

Comment: Is it hard core rule ? to define module name with start capital letter ?

Comment: yes it is rule for package and module name

Comment: I have changed the whole module as per your guide line.
after that I am getting this error when

Declaration of Packt\SampleData\Block\Sampledata::_construct() should be compatible with Magento\Framewo
rk\View\Element\Template::_construct()
public function _construct(
  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
  \Packt\SampleData\Model\SampledataFactory $SampledataFactory, array $data = []
 ){
  $this->_SampledataFactory = $SampledataFactory;
  parent::_construct($context,$data);
 }